# In jquery autocomplete, how to disply label and submit the id corresponding to label

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I have a search field which use jquery autocomplete.In this textbox that drops down a list of employee names suggested by the autocomplete.But when my form is submitted I don't want the persons name sent along with form, I want the employee id sent with the form.How I can do that?

```
<input id="employee">
<input type="hidden" id="employee_id">
```

Above given is the textfield I used

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/accounts/allEmp',
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var arr = [];
            arr = data.employee;
            $("#employee").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: arr,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#employee").val(ui.item.name);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#employee").val(ui.item.name);
                    $("#employee_id").val(ui.item.id);
                    return false;
                }
            })
                .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li>")
                        .append("<a>" + item.name)
                        .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    });
});
```

This is the script I used.While I entering characters in the textfield it doesn't show any results but when remove those characters from textfield it will show all the entities(sorting is not working).And the array look like

```
array="employee": 
[ { "name": "a", "id": 1 }, 
{ "name": "b", "id": 2 },
{ "name": "c", "id": 3 } ]
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you control server side of source url? If so I suggest you use `"value"` property name instead of `"name"` as described in [autocomplete api](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).
Otherwise you can modify that array in place and add `"value"` properties on the fly.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcq7E/) I just created from your snippet. With click on "send" it crashes I don't know why but if you look in your developer's panel network request is getting through with params:

```
employee[name]:Fred
employee[id]:first
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/dHsVL/)**

JS code:

```
var data = {
    json: "{\"employee\":[{\"value\":\"A\",\"id\":\"1\"},{\"value\":\"B\",\"id\":\"2\"},{\"value\":\"C\",\"id\":\"3\"}]}"
}


$(function () { 

$('#submit').click(function(){
    alert('Employee name = '+$('#employee_name').val()+' Employee id = '+$('#employee_id').val());    
});   

    $.ajax({
        url:"/echo/json/",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var arr = data.employee;
            $("#employee_name").autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: arr,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#employee_name").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#employee_id").val(ui.item.id);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form>
    Employee name (Type like "A" or "B" or "C")<br>
    <input id="employee_name" name="employee_name">
    <br>
    Selected Employee id (hidden field):        
    <input type="text" id="employee_id" name="employee_id" readonly>
    <br>    
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="check_fields()">
```